# acceder al directorio public_html con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola amigos actualmente necesito acceder a un directorio en mi hosting con laravel a una carpeta que se encuentra ubicada en el siguiente directorio:

```
carpetadomains/dominio/carpetapublic_html/carpeta2/carpeta3
```

Entonces configure el siguente disco

```
'files' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/domains/midominio/public_html/carpeta2',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'permissions' => [
            'file' => [
                'public' => 0664,
            ],
            'dir' => [
            'public' => 0775,            
            ],
        ],        
    ],
```

pero trato de hacer esto:

```
 $fileList = Storage::disk('files')->allFiles($folder);
```

imrpime esto: []

Me pudieran orientar para saber como accedo a esa ruta? En la misma tengo un archivo que se debería listar cuando acceda, gracias de antemano

Comment: El helper [public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-public-path) apunta al directorio `public/`. Podrías usar otro helper como [base_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-base-path) y concatenarle el directorio `public_html/` y los demás subdirectorios, o crear un helper propio para que apunte a `public_html()`.

Comment: gracias pero yo estaria necesitando acceder a la carpeta public_html, y con base_path('public_html'); dice: The "/home/11111/miproyecto/public_html" directory does not exist.

Comment: el tema es que mi proyecto no lo tengo en la carpeta public_html, están al mismo nivel entonces necesitaria acceder a un archivoque tengo en la carpeta public_html

Comment: Ah, ok. Lo único que se me ocurre entonces, es que pongas el path absoluto al directorio `public_html` como variable de entorno y lo tomes de ahí en la configuración del disco.

Comment: Gracias pero no comprendo muy bien lo que me dices, modificar el .env? el tema es que el sistema es productivo y no me gustaria modificar el .env

Comment: Sí, decía agregar una variable en el archivo .env, creo que sería lo más limpio.